# Find the determinant of the following $5\times5$ trigonometric matrix(unit in radian):

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, determinant

Find the determinant of the following $5\times5$ trigonometric matrix(unit in radian):
$$\textbf{A}=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
\sin(1) && \sin(2) && \sin(3) && \sin(4) && \sin(5)\\
\sin(2) && \sin(3) && \sin(4) && \sin(5) && \sin(6)\\
\sin(3) && \sin(4) && \sin(5) && \sin(6) && \sin(7)\\
\sin(4) && \sin(5) && \sin(6) && \sin(7) && \sin(8)\\
\sin(5) && \sin(6) && \sin(7) && \sin(8) && \sin(9)\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: It seems you are new to MSE. I suggest that you read the rules about making good questions and how to write with TeX code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\det(A)=0$ because there exists a linear combination of the first 3 columns of $A$ which is zero:

$$\tag{1}\begin{pmatrix}\sin(1)\\ \sin(2)\\ \sin(3)\\ \sin(4)\\ \sin(5)\\ \end{pmatrix}-2 \cos(1) \begin{pmatrix}\sin(2)\\ \sin(3)\\ \sin(4)\\ \sin(5)\\ \sin(6)\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\sin(3)\\ \sin(4)\\ \sin(5)\\ \sin(6)\\ \sin(7)\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\0\\0\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

due to relationship:

$$\tag{2}\sin(a)-2 \cos(1) \sin(a+1)+\sin(a+2)=0, $$

valid for any value of a (this can be verified by using addition formulas)

Another way to present (1) is that

$$\tag{3}V_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2 \cos(1)\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} \ \text{ belongs to the kernel of} \ A.$$

---

Something more can be said about $A$.

There are two other elements in the kernel:

$$\tag{4}V_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-2 \cos(1)\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \  V_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\-2 \cos(1)\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Moreover, $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are independent (echelon form).

Therefore, $dim Ker A \geq 3$. Consequently, $rank(A) \leq 2$ .

In fact, $rank(A) = 2$, because the $2$ first columns of $A$ are independent.

The fact that $rank(A)=2$ can be revealed in a different way ; indeed, $A$ can be written as a product of $2$ elementary rank-$2$ matrices in this way:

$$\tag{5}A=\begin{pmatrix}\sin(1)&\cos(1)\\\sin(2)&\cos(2)\\\sin(3)&\cos(3)\\\sin(4)&\cos(4)\\\sin(5)&\cos(5) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\cos(0)&\cos(1)&\cos(2)&\cos(3)&\cos(4)\\
\sin(0)&\sin(1)&\sin(2)&\sin(3)&\sin(4) \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I just added to my answer a new comment about the rank of $A$.

Comment: Hey Jean, would you explain to me how did you combine the first three columns into one?

Comment: What I mean is how did you add the coefficient of -2cos(1) just to column 2?  Also, why you can use column 1 minus column 2 and plus column 3? Because, from my understanding of matrices, we are not allowed to do that.

Comment: We are allowed to do that ! You can replace any column by itself + any linear combination (not only with coefficients 1 and -1) of the other columns without modifying the value of the determinant.

Comment: See for example "theorem DRCMA" in (http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-PDM.html)

Comment: A last comment : in fact, I draw your attention on the kernel explanation (equ. (3)) which in fact is a more "long range" formulation. But maybe, you haven't done enough linear algebra till now to switch easily from (1) to (3).